# Second item is blank when adding view to android linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I'm trying to dynamically add views to a linear layout, but it's failing to show the second view if I'm attempting to add two views to the linear layout. The second view is completely blank.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Leads That Need Action Today"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/action_leads_list_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Overdue Tasks"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/overdue_tasks_list_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

-Loops through json array to call the function that adds the views to linear layout

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(rsp);
for(int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++){
    JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
    Lead lead = new Lead();
    lead.name = jObj.getString("FirstName") + " " + jObj.getString("LastName");


    addViewToLayout(lead);
}



private void addViewToLayout(Lead lead){
            View view = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_today_task, null);

 TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(lead.name);

            actionsListLeadLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: Tis a little bit hard to tell from what you've posted. Do post more snippets. :)

Comment: Are you sure the second view is viewable (within the viewable area)? Maybe it's offscreen and you just need to make your layout scrollable. Try nesting your LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView.

Comment: Added more details in code.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Can the second text be empty, so it is not visible?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure it out so I decided to just do a custom expandable list view.